# Widget filtering with Bokeh

Tags: python, callback, widget, bokeh

**How can I filter a dataframe with a Bokeh widget and use callbacks without relying in ColumnDataSource(df)?**

My dataframe columns are: ['Date', 'demand', 'Battery'] and would like to filter by Battery but, ColumnDataSource requires a dataframe with independent columns. My datafame has everything mixed in those 3 columns.

The example code below uses a callback for just one column. I would like to update and filter selecting all possible demand and dates by the serial number of the Battery.

```
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['x']= demand.loc[demand['Battery']==Battery,['Date']].to_numpy().flatten()
df['y']= demand.loc[demand['Battery']==Battery,['demand']].to_numpy().flatten()

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
bat= Battery
p=figure(x_axis_type='datetime',y_axis_label='Demand', plot_width=1000, plot_height=450)
p.line('x','y', source=source)
p.title.text='Battery' + '  ' + bat
p.title.align = 'center'

show(p)
    
# Create a dropdown Select widget: select    
select_menu= Select(title="Battery:", options=['5e6a62df','aasdfsds4330a'], value='5e6a62df')
callback= CustomJS(args={'source':source2}, code=""" 
                   
        // print the selectd value of the select widget - 
        // this is printed in the browser console.
        // cb_obj is the callback object, in this case the select 
        // widget. cb_obj.value is the selected value.
        console.log(' changed selected option', cb_obj.value);

        // create a new variable for the data of the column data source
        // this is linked to the plot
        var data = source.data;

        // allocate the selected column to the field for the y values
        data['y'] = data[cb_obj.value];

        // register the change - this is required to process the change in 
        // the y values
        source.change.emit();
""") 

# Attach the update_plot callback to the 'value' property of select
select2.callback=callback
show(row(select2,p))
```

Comment: "ColumnDataSource requires a dataframe with independent columns" - that is absolutely not true. CDS does not impose any constraints on the data. You can have a column `X` and a column `X * 2` with no problem.

Comment: Thanks @EugenePakhomov for your reply but I may have not explained well. I meant by independent that I cannot filter like in Pandas because I am passing a column via JS

`// allocate the selected column to the field for the y values data['y'] = data[cb_obj.value];`

Comment: I see. Don't do that. Instead, just pass _all_ data into a CDS and point the `y` field of the glyph to the appropriate column name. Here's an example, notice the line with `{field: active}`: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/providing-data-for-a-multi-line-from-a-dataframe-having-trouble-figuring-out-how-to-restructure-the-dataframe-use-multi-lines-syntax/5038/24?u=p-himik

Comment: Thanks @EugenePakhomov, I will have a look on it.